Cannot find ID when establishing trust between AD and Red Hat IdM
I have established a trust relationship between Active Directory (AD) and Red Hat Identity Manager (IdM). After that, I added a client host managed by IdM. However, I am experiencing an issue where the client sometimes finds user IDs and sometimes does not.
I would appreciate your assistance in troubleshooting this issue, as it affects user access to our Linux resources.

the client sometimes finds user IDs and sometimes does not. is the client connecting to AD but the user account is not found? If so, is it for recently created accounts?

I just checked, and when I ran the command sssctl domain-status ad.example.com, it returned "Unable to get online status," and this issue affects all AD users.
